# Javascript - Why am I Getting NAN error with my function

Tags: javascript, function, nan

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var sheep = prompt("How many sheeps do we have in the park?");
  var rangers = prompt("How many rangers do we have in the park?");

  function feedPerRanger (sheep, rangers) {
     alert("Each Park Ranger should load " + sheep*2/rangers + 
           " lb(s) of feed into his/her BART today.");
  }

  feedPerRanger ();
</script>
```

Hello

I'm still a beginner so this is probably a rookie mistake. The script is suppose to alert the user as to how much feed each park ranger is suppose to load on to his/her BART. It's suppose to be 2 lbs per every sheep divided by the number of rangers. I keep getting the following NAN error. Can anyone explain why?

"Each Park Ranger should load NaN lb(s) of feed into his/her BART today."

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: The parameters for the `feedPerRanger` function **shadow** the outer variables (because they have the same name). And since you **call the function with no arguments**, the parameters both are set as `undefined`. I would just pass the two variables to the function. To make the problem more apparent, make the parameter names different from the variable names and see what happens when you use each set in the calculation

Comment: A little bit about this on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope#Name_conflicts

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
function feedPerRanger (sheep, rangers) {
    alert("Each Park Ranger should load " + sheep*2/rangers + " lb(s) of feed into his/her BART today.");
}
```

with this:

```
function feedPerRanger () {
    alert("Each Park Ranger should load " + sheep*2/rangers + " lb(s) of feed into his/her BART today.");
}
```

Now it works; but (in my opinion) it is not the better way to do what you want.

You may use your function properly, passing two generic parameter as following:

```
function feedPerRanger(sheep, rangers) {
    alert("Each Park Ranger should load " + sheep*2/rangers + " lb(s) of feed into his/her BART today.");
}

var sheep = prompt("How many sheeps do we have in the park?");
var rangers = prompt("How many rangers do we have in the park?");

feedPerRanger(sheep, rangers);
```

Comment: Please, if you think this is the right answer, consider to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** - as Ian has [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24193399/javascript-why-am-i-getting-nan-error-with-my-function#comment37349281_24193399) change the names of the parameters.

You should pass the `sheep` and `rangers` variables to the function. 
And you should also check if they contain numbers. Consider this:

```
var sheep = prompt("How many sheeps do we have in the park?");
// sheep = "some random string";
// alert ( sheep / 2 );
```

I can press "h" or write whatever I want. Look at [**`prompt`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.prompt) from MDN

> result (of prompt) is a string containing the text entered by the user, or the value null.

So add a little check if the variable is not a number with [**`isNaN`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) like this:

```
isNaN(sheep)
```

Also I can press **Cancel** in the **prompt**, then sheep or rangers will be **`null`**. If you change the function like this, there will be no chance to have another **`NaN`** :

```
function feedPerRanger(sheep, rangers) {
    if ((sheep && !isNaN(sheep)) && (rangers && !isNaN(rangers))) {
        alert("Each Park Ranger should load " + sheep * 2 / rangers +
            " lb(s) of feed into his/her BART today.");
    } else {
        alert("please use numbers");
    }
}

var sheepCount = prompt("How many sheeps do we have in the park?");
var rangersCount = prompt("How many rangers do we have in the park?");

feedPerRanger(sheepCount, rangersCount);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AcuM7/)

Comment: Great suggestion. I should definitely check to make sure the parameters are numbers. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Your function definition accepts two parameters.

```
function feedPerRanger (sheep, rangers)
```

You give none in your call:

```
feedPerRanger ();
```

(Additionally, there's no space between the name of the function and the parentheses)

When you create your function definition, you're giving names to local variables. That is, `sheep` and `ranger` are the names given to the parameters passed so that they can be used in the function. So, when you create the function definition, `sheep` and `ranger` are not the variables you created above.

There are two ways to fix this.

1. Remove your parameters from the function definition:

   ```
   function feedPerRanger(){...}
   ```
2. Pass in your variables as parameters to the function:

   ```
   function feedPerRanger(numSheep, numRangers){
     alert("Each Park Ranger should load " + numSheep*2/numRangers + " lb(s) of feed into his/her BART today.");
   }

   feedPerRanger(sheep, rangers)
   ```